Setting two classes to the same width/max-width using Javascript
I'm trying to dynamically set two divs to the same max-width using javascript.. I have this so far:
window.onload = function setWidth() {
  var one = document.getElementsByClassName("adsm-skin site-main");
  var two = document.getElementsByClassName("pn-print-page");
    style = window.getComputedStyle(one);
    wdt = style.getPropertyValue("max-width");
    two.style.maxWidth = wdt;
}

However it's not working (the .pn-print-page isn't registering having any max-width at all on page load when I'd like it to match .adsm-skin .site-main)
I've also tried this:
window.onload = function () {
function setWidth() {
  var one = document.querySelector(".other-div");
  var two = document.querySelector(".pn-print-page");
  style = window.getComputedStyle(one);
  wdt = style.getPropertyValue('width');
  two.style.width = wdt;
}
};

No width is being added to pn-print-page either.. Is there something wrong with the code? If not do you know any other ways of doing this using javascript..? Thanks in advance

Please put your script and some HTML in a demo using the post editor. Show us what's happening. See [ask] for tips.

Regarding your first attempt, see Why does getElementsByClassName() not work?

FYI, there's no jQuery here. You should probably remove that tag. It's best to write raw JavaScript for tasks like this in 2024 anyway.

"match .adsm-skin .site-main" - the selector .adsm-skin .site-main is not the same as the selector .adsm-skin.site-main.   .getElementsByClassName("adsm-skin site-main"); is the same as $(".adsm-skin.site-main") (which is not what you say you want).   Perhaps including some HTML would determine if site-main is a descendent of adsm-skin or if it's a single element with both classes.  See [mcve].

Always debug your selectors: console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("adsm-skin site-main").length) - likely == 0

any other ways of doing this - looks like a solution for css flex-box... "using javascript"... oh well.

The only problem I can think of is that your other-div doesn't have rule max-width in the css:
.other-div {
    max-width: 300px;
}

The getPropertyValue() method returns a string containing the value of the specified CSS property. If the property is not specified, it returns an empty string.


function setWidth() {
    var one = document.querySelector(".other-div")
    var two = document.querySelector(".pn-print-page")
    style = window.getComputedStyle(one)
    wdt = style.getPropertyValue("max-width")
    two.style.width = wdt
}

window.onload = function () {
    setWidth()
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.other-div {
  max-width: 300px;
}
<div class="other-div">other-div</div>
<div class="pn-print-page">pn-print-page</div>



